# Trying to update separate table with SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

Learning Python to use in ArcGis 10.2.

I want to get value from a certain field from one attribute table into another attribute table. IN PT1, If Meas of Object1 > Meas of Object2, then  in SPL1 End = Punkt_ID of Object1 and Start = Punkt_ID of Object2

Like this:

[image]

So I have written this bit (based on existing scripts) where individual segments are used to select points in order to update the Split_Lines attribute table

```
## Update field End with max value
OIDField = arcpy.Describe(SplitLines).OIDFieldName
Lines = arcpy.UpdateCursor(SplitLines)
for Line in Lines:
    LineId = OIDField
    Where_clause = '"' + OIDField + '"=' +str(LineId) 
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (SplitLines, "Current_Line", Where_clause)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management ("Points_Lyr","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE","Current_Line", "0.02 METERS")
    pcur = arcpy.SearchCursor("Points_Lyr")
    prow = pcur.next()
    p1val = prow.getValue("MEAS")
    p1HH = prow.getValue("HH")
    p1ID = prow.getValue("Punkt_ID")
    prow = pcur.next()
    p2val = prow.getValue("MEAS")
    p2HH = prow.getValue("HH")
    p2ID = prow.getValue("Punkt_ID")

if p2val > p1val:
    Line.setValue("End", p2ID)
    Line.setValue("Start", p1ID)
    Line.setValue("HH_Stromab", p1HH)
    Line.setValue("HH_Stromauf", p2HH)

else:
    Line.setValue("End", p1ID)
    Line.setValue("Start", p2ID)
    Line.setValue("HH_Stromab", p2HH)
    Line.setValue("HH_Stromauf", p1HH)
Lines.updateRow(Line)
del prow
del pcur
```

I am almost there, only the Search Cursor on the Selected Points doesn't seem to update for each new selection and copy the Value of Punkt_ID =1 and Punkt_ID =2.

Like this:
[image]

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You need to use an UpdateCursor to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you split the lines at the points?  If so, a spatial join followed by field calc's with a codeblock might work.

Comment: You should print your Where_clause. I don't think it returns what you think it should. It looks like it should return: "OID" = OID. Use this instead: LineId = Line.getValue(OIDField)

Comment: @crmackey, the update Cursor is applied on Lines (SplitLine).

Comment: @gm70560, I did try that too, but the aim is to have a python script rather than a tool based on model builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting the code which should fulfill your requirement (based on my understanding of your requirement).

```
# required import
import arcpy

# path of Points_lyr feature class/table (point)
point_fc = r'D:\Python\ScratchDatabase\Geodatabase.gdb\Point'

# related fields #first field 'MEAS' to compare and second field 'Punkt_ID' to assign
# as you are taking other fields too (seen in your code). you can add those like
# point_flds = ['MEAS', 'Punkt_ID', 'HH']
# and map them as
# line_flds = ['OID@','Start', 'End', 'HH_Stromab', 'HH_Stromauf']
point_flds = ['MEAS', 'Punkt_ID', 'HH']

# path of split_Lines feature class (Line)
line_fc = r'D:\Python\ScratchDatabase\Geodatabase.gdb\Line'

# line fields #first field to get OBJECTID of current line segment,
# second field 'Start' to assign start id (Punkt_ID) and
# third field 'End' to assign end id (Punkt_ID)
# you can add
line_flds = ['OID@','Start', 'End', 'HH_Stromab', 'HH_Stromauf']

# for search by location to find and select
point = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(point_fc)

# update the values of line feature class
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(line_fc, line_flds) as update_cursor:
    for row in update_cursor:
        # create where clause
        where = '"OBJECTID"={}'.format(row[0])

        # take one segment at a time
        line = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(line_fc, where_clause=where)

        # apply selection on point feature class
        # change the criteria accordingly to suit your problem in distance
        selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(point, 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', line, "0.02 METERS", "NEW_SELECTION")
        comp_list = []
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selection, point_flds) as cursor:
            for search_row in cursor:
                # add all point which comes after select by location
                comp_list.append(search_row)
        # sort on the basis of 'MEAS' value
        sort = sorted(comp_list, key= lambda x: x[0])
        # assign smallest 'MEAS' value 'Punkt_ID' to 'Start'
        row[1] = sort[0][1]
        # assign largest 'MEAS' value 'Punkt_ID' to 'End'
        row[2] = sort[-1][1]
        # assign 'HH' value to 'HH_Stromab' for smallest 'MEAS'
        row[3] = sort[0][2]
        # assign 'HH' value to 'HH_Stromauf' for largest 'MEAS'
        row[4] = sort[-1][2]
        # update the line row
        update_cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: This Looks like a very elegant solution and it worked well. Could you please explain what means "key= lambda x: x[0]"? I replace "line = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(line_fc, where_clause=where)" by "arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(SplitLines,"current_line", where)" in order to not get multiple layers of single Segment. Many thanks!

Comment: @PMessager: To understand `key= lambda x: x[0]`. Please check [Python HowTo](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)

Comment: @PMessager: both ways to make feature classes are same, it creates in_memory feature class. But, by using `line = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(line_fc, where_clause=where)`, we can have more control on the feature class as you have it in `line` variable. But by this way `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(SplitLines,"current_line", where)`. it may throw an error `ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000725: Output Layer: Dataset current_line already exists.
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).`
 if you haven't set `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

Comment: arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True is implemented. Now I am trying to get out of the hardcoding to set the script as a tool...